# I am not able to type a space with spacebar, instead of that I have to press shift+spacebar

Tags: visual-studio-code

Recently I updated my VScode and changed some font settings of it. When I start editing my code I was not able to add a space with the help of the spacebar instead of that I have to press shift+spacebar, which is quite a lot of work to do every time.

I even tried to uninstall vscode completely by deleting .vscode file from C:\Users\USER_NAME.vscode. But when I again installed it, all the settings which I had modified and spacebar problem was still there.

Comment: Could it have something to do with a third-party keyboard shortcut app (e.g. AuoHotKey or Clavier) or  language setting? If you have a choice of language, try switching.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik it is working normally in other editors like subline text this issue is only in vs code.

Answer (score 0):

Click File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts.
There is a triple-dot (...) at the top-right hand corner.
Click on that (...) and select "Show User Keybindings"
You may find some mapping related to space bar.
Delete the listed space bar related keybinding only.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly this with VSCodium / Code on Xfce. Turned out the system shortcut to change keyboard layout caused interference. I had it assigned to `ctrl + space`, and this ruined `space` for the editor.